# Unable to DataBind asp:Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I read online that if I want to make a data binding expression inline I have to call the databind method on the Page_Load function. However I am unable to access the button control in the code behind for some reason. I have access to all the other buttons on my form except the one I want. Here is some code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="CartButton" runat="server" Text="View Cart <%# Session["Counter"].ToString() %>" OnClick="List_Items"  />
```

and

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CartButton.DataBind();
    }
```

This gives me an error that 'CartButton' does not exist in the current context. Running the page without the DataBind method call returns an error telling me that my

> > > The server tag is not well formed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you past more wrapping aspx code? It looks that you misspelled somewhere in your page.

Comment: for databinding you should specify the data source first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["Counter"].ToString() %>'/>
```

May this will help you.

Regards

AB Vyas

Comment: I think this worked it gave me a null reference exception but I think that is related to the Session["Counter"]. Does that mean that I am unable to add text along side the server directives? How should I add the text I want?

Comment: I got it to work using `<%# "Cart" + Session["Counter"].ToString() %>` thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think in this situation you don't need the databinging. Try to do something like that instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CartButton.Text = String.Format("View Cart {0}", Session["Counter"].ToString());
}

<asp:Button ID="CartButton" runat="server" OnClick="List_Items"  />
```